# How to add formatting such as bold, italic, underscore, etc. to Kotlin documenation (KDoc)

Tags: kotlin, formatting, code-documentation, kdoc

I found the page *[Documenting Kotlin Code](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html)* in the official Kotlin Reference.

Yet, I could not find out how to highlight certain parts of the documentation, e.g., marking it as italic or bold.

I am new to Kotlin, coming from Java, and have previously only been using JavaDoc, where we used `<i>` and `<b>` HTML tags to highlight parts in the documentation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As I wrote this question, I found the answer to it.
Silly me, the link I was looking for even was [on the page I referenced](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html) in the question.

So, I will write an answer to my own question, probably someone else can profit from it in the future.

The documentation states:

> **Inline Markup**
>   For inline markup, KDoc uses the regular [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) syntax, extended to support a shorthand syntax for linking to other elements in the code.

So, to highlight a few points of [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax):

- Markdown treats asterisks (`*`) and underscores (`_`) as indicators of emphasis. Text wrapped with one `*` or `_` will be wrapped with an HTML `<em>` tag; double `*`’s or `_`’s will be wrapped with an HTML `<strong>` tag. Typically, a single asterik results in *italic*, while double asterik results in **bold**.
- Headers can be started with `#` (h1), `##` (h2), or `###` (h3). For example: `# This is an H1`
- Code can be wrapped in backticks
- Quotes start with a right arrow (`>`)
- Markdown also supports unordered and ordered lists
- [... and more](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list)